# Read local file from Google App with Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files to the blobstore in my Google App without using a form. But I'm stuck at how to get the app to read my local file. I'm pretty new to python and Google Apps but after some cut and pasting I've ended up with this:

```
import webapp2
import urllib
import os

from google.appengine.api import files
from poster.encode import multipart_encode

class Upload(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    # Create the file in blobstore
    file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')

    # Get the local file path from an url param
    file_path = self.request.get('file')

    # Read the file
    file = open(file_path, "rb")
    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"file": file})
    data = str().join(datagen) # this is supposedly memory intense and slow

    # Open the blobstore file and write to it
    with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(data)

    # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
    files.finalize(file_name)

    # Get the file's blob key
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
```

The problem now is I don't really know how to get hold of the local file

Comment: Why without a form? How are you expecting the user to choose the file and upload it without a file input?

Comment: I'm making a standalone program in which files are saved and then are supposed to be uploaded

Comment: When you say a local file are you trying to submit a file that you upload with your python code or are you trying to submit a file that is on your local computer? If its the former it is not possible because GAE does not allow access of the local files as a security protocol. As the former I would say you will need an upload field and web page form.

Comment: So the application assumes what file they wish to upload?

Comment: Yes the application knows what file to upload, in other words it does what an upload form usually does. But I want all my interaction to be preformed within my standalone application (which is a C# application) and not through a webpage.

Comment: You need a handler that generates the upload URL for you. The application will first have to post to that handler, then post the file itself to the handler you've just posted. Application uses standard http/url libraries that handle encoding etc.

Comment: Don't you think it would be a problem if any webapp could read files from your local drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read from the local file system from within the application itself, you will need to  use http POST to send the file to the app.

You can certainly do this from within another application - you just need to create the mime multipart message with the file content and POST it to your app, the sending application will just have to create the http request that you will post to the app manually. You should have a read on how to create a mime mulitpart message using c#.

Comment: Thanks you made me realize I wasn't looking at the wrong end altogether